# Why does ice cream not go back to its original form upon refreezing?

Tags: thermodynamics, food-chemistry

I came from a birthday party and someone gave me a sundae. I'm already full so I just decided to eat it at home. After arriving at home the sundae melted. So I left it in the freezer overnight. When I looked at my sundae it just formed ice crystals. It didn't went back to its original form. Why is that?. Why is it when I do this to ordinary ice cream it goes back to it's original form?

Answer (score 7):

Ice cream is a frozen emulsion mixed with air. When the ice cream melted, the air escaped. When you re-froze it, it formed a solid mass.